# how to get data from device uuid and send it as sms in ionic framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Im developing a mobile app for a client and the main feature of the app is to fetch data from a device and send it via sms but im using cordova device plugin to get device uuid but don't know how to send it as sms, pls help. this is my HTML: `

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function() {})

.controller('DeviceCtrl', function($ionicPlatform, $scope, $cordovaDevice) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
$scope.$apply(function() {
// sometimes binding does not work! :/
if(window.StatusBar) {
// org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
// getting device infor from $cordovaDevice
var device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice();

        $scope.manufacturer = device.manufacturer;
        $scope.model = device.model;
        $scope.platform = device.platform;
        $scope.uuid = device.uuid;

    });

});
})
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="Device Information">

    <ion-content>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="item item-divider">
                Your device information!
            </div>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li class="item">
                        Manufacturer : {{manufacturer}}
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        Model : {{model}}
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        Platform : {{platform}}
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        UUID : {{uuid}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item item-divider text-right">
                 
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

`
with this above code i can get the device uuid but the problem now is how to send uuid info and send it as sms

Answer (score 1):

Use the Cordova SMS plugin to send sms .
(https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin/blob/master/readme.md)
Here is the work flow

1.get the device uuid via device plugin

2.send this as the argument of SMS code.
    Place this code after `device.uuid.`

```
var deviceid=device.uuid;
//pass the deviceid

 sendsms(deviceid);

function sendsms(deviceid){
 var app = {
    sendSms: function() {
        var number ="mobile no";
        var message ="deviceid is"+deviceid;
        alert(number);
        alert(message);`

        //CONFIGURATION
        var options = {
            replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
            android: {
                intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
                //intent: '' // send SMS without open any other app
            }
        };

        var success = function () { alert('Message sent successfully'); };
        var error = function (e) { alert('Message Failed:' + e); };
        sms.send(number, message, options, success, error);
    }
};
}
```

Comment: please @shammon, can you pls show me with code. thanks